# Difficulty deducing derivatives of particular summation formulas

Tags: derivatives, summation, logarithms

I have difficulty concluding the derivatives of the following:

$$y=\ln\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^ng_j\cdot e^{xE_j}\bigg)$$
and
$$y=x\cdot \sum_{j=1}^n \bigg(g_j \cdot \frac{N}{\sum_{j=1}^ng_j\cdot e^{xE_j}}\cdot e^{xE_j}\cdot E_j\bigg)$$
Note that $x$ does not change during the summation. Are these possible to solve? If so, how?

**EDIT:** I have made a mistake when copying the second formula, I have corrected it.

Comment: What derivatives are you taking? $\frac{\partial y}{\partial E_j}$, or $\frac{\partial y}{\partial g_j}$, presumably not $\frac{dy}{dx}$ since you're suggesting $x$ is constant. Is this something from statistical mechanics by any chance?

Comment: He is saying that $x$ is the variable to differentiate wrt, but the series index is not $x$.

Here what I'd do is say $e^y = \sum$ and then you can differentiate both sides wrt $x$ (implicit differentiation), giving $\frac{dy}{dx}e^y = \frac{d}{dx}\Sigma$.

To differentiate the series, just differentiate each term and sum them together.

Comment: For the second one I'd guess the answer is just $y=N$ with derivative zero, but seeing as there is probably $N = N_j$ i.e. $N$ varying, what you should do is take $(\sum_{j=1}^n g_j e^{xE_j})^{-1}$ out as a multiple, and use the product rule of differentiation.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst For the 1st formula, if $\frac{dy}{dx}e^y = \frac{d}{dx}\Sigma$  then I get $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n(g_j \cdot E_j \cdot e^{xE_j})$. But a different source is telling me otherwise saying that the derivative of $\ln(g(x))$ is $\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$, thus $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n (g_j \cdot E_j e^{xE_j})}{\sum_{j=1}^n (g_j \cdot e^{xE_j})}$.

For the second formula, I made a mistake; the summation itself should be multiplied by $x$ as well (I corrected it in the OP). The $N$ is a constant and does not vary during the summation.

Answer (score 1):

If
$y
=\ln\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^ng_j\cdot e^{xE_j}\bigg)
$
then,
since
$(\ln(f(x))'
=\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
y'
&=\dfrac{(\sum_{j=1}^ng_j e^{xE_j})'}{\sum_{j=1}^ng_je^{xE_j}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^ng_jE_j e^{xE_j}}{\sum_{j=1}^ng_je^{xE_j}}\\
\end{array}
$

For your second $y$,
you need to make the index
in the inner sum
different than
the index in the outer sum.

$\begin{array}\\
y
&=x \sum_{j=1}^n \bigg(g_j \dfrac{N}{\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k}} e^{xE_j}\bigg)\\
&=N\sum_{j=1}^n \bigg(g_j \dfrac{xe^{xE_j}}{\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k}} \bigg)\\
&=N\sum_{j=1}^n g_jy_j(x)\\
\end{array}
$

where
$y_j(x)
= \dfrac{xe^{xE_j}}{\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k}} 
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
y_j'(x)
&= \left(\dfrac{xe^{xE_j}}{\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k}}\right)'\\
&= \dfrac{(\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k})(xe^{xE_j})'-(\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k})'(e^{xE_j})}{(\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k})^2}\\
&= \dfrac{(\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k})((xE_j+1)e^{xE_j})-(\sum_{k=1}^ng_kE_ke^{xE_k})(e^{xE_j})}{(\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k})^2}\\
&= e^{xE_j}\dfrac{(xE_j+1)\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k}-\sum_{k=1}^ng_kE_ke^{xE_k}}{(\sum_{k=1}^ng_ke^{xE_k})^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Now put this in
$y'(x)
=\sum_{j=1}^n g_jNy_j'(x)
$,
do any possible simplifications,
correct any errors I may have made,
and you are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm so sorry, I have a mistake in the OP, the second formula within the summation should be multiplied by $E_j$ such that $y=x\cdot \sum_{j=1}^n (g_j \cdot \frac{N}{\sum_{j=1}^ng_j\cdot e^{xE_j}}\cdot e^{xE_j}\cdot E_j)$. Not sure if this would change the whole derivation.

Comment: Nope. Just changes the final summation. The $y_j$ remain the same.

Comment: Such that $y'(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n E_j g_jNy_j'(x)$?

Comment: Yup. If $E-J$ is there, use it.

Comment: I think your $x$ in the denominator of $y'_j(x)$ should not be there.

Comment: Probably right. I'll fix it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any other errors. Could you please recheck this?